# ROALP vs MOLAP difference

Tags: data-warehouse, business-intelligence, olap-cube

I have gone though various videos, tutorials and forum but i did not get the answer for my questions.

1. Is ROLAP also called as cubes?
2. In ROLAP, Data is stored and fetched from the main data warehouse.
   MOLAP not referring to physical tales?
   Somewhere i have seen MOLAP stores the data in Proprietary database, but i 
   don't know what is Proprietary database.
3. Is the cubes are technique which are build on data mart/DWH?
4. Cube is are visual representation?
5. And also reporting tools are connected with DM/DWH or cubes? 6. MOLAP cubes stores the data physically?

Comment: 5. And also reporting tools are connected with DM/DWH or cubes?
6. MOLAP cubes stores the data physically?

Comment: There's a lot to cover here! i'm not sure whether asking here will give more information or explain in a different way to online videos, tutorials and websites. Would it help if you explain what you don't understand?

Comment: Best if you edit your question to include 5 and 6, rather than as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot to cover here, and it is unlikely this will answer all your questions but might help point you in the right direction.

1. ROLAP (Relational OLAP) can be achieved with cubes and other OLAP technologies. Cubes are OLAP technologies. But Cubes may use other approaches to OLAP (HOLAP, MOLAP) which are not ROLAP.
2. MOLAP does store its data in physical form, often loaded into memory for performance reasons. But the point is, it is storage that is part of the cube technology, not the same tables as the data warehouse. In MOLAP, the data from the data warehouse is first copied to the cube. A proprietary technology is simply a technology used by the Cube to store data, which may be designed specially to store cube data.
3. Cubes are a technique that can be considered part of the overall data mart and DWH, but they are in addition to the main data warehouse in which the data is stored/queried. They provide: fast performance of querying, and more user friendly presentation of the data held within a data warehouse.
4. Cubes are not a visual representation, they are a place where the user can see that data is available for querying, and make queries of it. The user can of course use a cube to visually represent the data they have queried.
5. Reporting tools can query data from either the DM/DWH or cubes, or both! Both can be considered places where reporting tools can get their data.
6. MOLAP cubes do store their data physically, but normally the cube designer doesn't have to create the underlying tables/storage for this themselves. The cube designer designs the cube and the cube technology stores the data. Usually MOLAP cubes load the data on a regular basis from the DWH into their own storage.

Comment: Thanks Rich!
Is it like ROLAP = Relational data modelling
and MOLAP = Multi dimensional modelling?

Comment: Relational Online Analytical Processing (indicating the data will come from a relational database although the query the user makes is to the cube) and Multidimensional Online Analytical Processing (indicating the data will come from the multidimensionally modelled cube itself and not the data warehouse.